# Class Cast Exception - Mouse event

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, mouseevent

A bit of context - I am creating a rudimentary implementation of Scrabble and the GUI relies on Java Swing and AWT. The code excerpt below contains the constructor for the Cell class (individual space on the Scrabble board). I am in the proof of concept phase and am testing the addition and removal of a hard-coded letter icon to an individual cell. Each cell is an individual JPanel with a JLabel (which, contains an ImageIcon of the letter). The code looks as though it works without error, BUT every 5-6 additions/removals (via mouse click) causes a class cast exception. The specific exception is:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cell cannot be cast to javax.swing.JLabel

I can't see where this exception would be caused, but more specifically why it only occurs after multiple successful additions and removals. Any insight greatly appreciated; I am a beginner to Java GUI.

```
public class Cell extends JPanel {

/*Tile Colors*/
public static Color twColor = new Color(255, 0, 0);
public static Color dwColor = new Color(255, 153, 255);
public static Color tlColor = new Color(0, 51, 255);
public static Color dlColor = new Color(102, 204, 255);
public static Color defaultColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);

private JLabel selected = null;
private JLabel clicked = null;
private JLabel letterIcon;
private ImageIcon defaultIcon;
private ImageIcon testImg;

public Cell(int xPos, int yPos, int premiumStatus) {

    defaultIcon = new ImageIcon ("img/transparent.png");
    testImg = new ImageIcon ("img/test.jpg"); // Letter image hard-coded for testing
    letterIcon = new JLabel("", defaultIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
    add(letterIcon);

    letterIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel clicked = (JLabel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
        System.out.println(clicked);
        if (clicked == null) {
          return;
        }
        if (selected != null) {
          selected.removeAll();
          selected.revalidate();
          selected.setIcon(defaultIcon);
          selected.repaint();
          System.out.println("Test");
          selected = null;
          return;
        }
        if (selected == null) {
          selected = clicked;
          selected.setIcon(testImg);
          selected.revalidate();
          selected.repaint();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is being cause by calling `getComponentAt(e.getPoint());` on the `Cell`, when the mouse coordinates have already been converted to the coordinate space of the `letterIcon`.

When a component is clicked, the `MouseEvent`'s point is automatically converted to the coordinate space of the component that the listener is registered to.

In your case, that is the `letterIcon`.  This means that a point at 0x0 is the top/left corner of the `letterIcon` (despite where it might physically be positioned).

So, calling `getComponentAt(e.getPoint())` is ask the `Cell` to return the component that corresponds to a position which is actually relative only to the `letterIcon`, which will (in most cases) return the `Cell` itself.

Instead, you should be simply using `MouseEvent#getComponent` to return the component that triggered the event, which will be the `letterIcon`

**Update with a simple example**

This is a simple example that sets up a `JLabel` as a mouse target.  When the mouse is clicked, both the label and it's parent container will paint a small dot based on the coordinates of the mouse click.

There is the added benefit that the parent container will also translate the click point to it's coordinate space and paint a second dot, which should be in the same click as the labels.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestMouseClicked {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMouseClicked();
    }

    public TestMouseClicked() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel clickMe;
        private Point clickPoint;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            clickMe = new JLabel("Click me") {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
//                    paintPoint(g, clickPoint);
                }
            };
            add(clickMe);
            clickMe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    clickPoint = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            paintPoint(g, clickPoint);
            if (clickPoint != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                // Convert the point from clickMe coordinate space to local coordinate space
                paintPoint(g, SwingUtilities.convertPoint(clickMe, clickPoint, this));
            }
        }

        protected void paintPoint(Graphics g, Point clickPoint) {
            if (clickPoint != null) {
                int size = 4;
                g.fillOval(clickPoint.x - size, clickPoint.y - size, size * 2, size * 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response! Not only does this change work, but I also now have a better understanding of the MouseEvent's behavior.

Comment: I've added a simple example to demonstrate what I've been saying, hope it helps